# Jquery find a span tag with specific style

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `span` tag inside `td` of a `table` with specific style `color:red`. I want to find that span tag and hide it below is the code I have:

**HTML :**

```
<table class="table_1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<span id="dynamically generated" style="color:red;">
Error! correct it.
</span> 
</td>
<td>
<span>
// Three links to three different sites
<a>
</a>
<a>
</a>
<a>
</a>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT** the id of first span is dynamically generated like "Span1" "Span2"....

**Jquery:**

```
     $("table.table_1 tr").each(function (n) {
        $(this).find('td:eq(0)').find('span').html("");
    });
```

The above jquery code is hiding both the `span` tags even though they are in different `td`. Am i doing something wrong? i Just want to hide the first span tag which has error message in it. Is there a way?

Comment: [I tested it](http://jsfiddle.net/N4ujL/) : only the first is hidden. Are you using a very old jquery ?

Comment: The code you show us is working (see my fiddle). The error is probably elsewhere.

Comment: works in jsfiddle but doesnt in my app... think there is some other script which is conflicting

Comment: I recommend you debug and use the console to log the intermediate objects, like `$(this).find('td:eq(0)')`.

Comment: I tried the simple method... I dont have much time so I added class and did a .html("") on that class.. it worked as expected.. but will debug to see why this is happening. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would put a **class** on the tr or td (like 'error'), then **hide()** it:

```
<span id="dynamically-generated" class="error">
Error! correct it.
</span>

...

$('table.table_1 .error').hide();
```

Hiding is much more elegant than calling html(''), because hide() won't destroy the contents. So if you want to display the error later, just call **show()**. :)

Finally, you should put the red color in your CSS:

```
.error { color:red; }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("table.table_1 tr span[style='color:red']:first")
```

or:

```
$(".table_1 span[style]:first")
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QEbgV/)

Comment: @dystroy the title is _find a span tag with specific style_ if OP code is working this is just an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LhWqb/3/)

```
$('.table_1 span').filter(function() {
    var colormatch= 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'; // match color:red

    return ( $(this).css('color') == colormatch);

}).css('display', 'none'); // hide the span​
```

Answer (score 1):

You could locate the word "Error" and remove it that way.

See here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QAXZz/) for an example, or below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table.table_1 tr td span").each(function() {
        if ($(this).html().lastIndexOf("Error") > 0) {
            $(this).html("");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's have a look at your markup:

> The ID and NAME elements must start with a letter i.e. upper case A to
>   Z or lower case a to z; a number is not allowed. After the first
>   letter any number of letters (a to z, A to Z), digits (0 to 9),
>   hyphens (-), underscores (_), colons (:) and periods (.) are allowed.

Source: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/valid-characters-html-id-attribute/

Because spaces are not allowed you should really use `id="dynamically-generated"` instead of `id="dynamically generated"`. Then you could simply do

```
$('#dynamically-generated').hide()
```

I would recommend to use a class attribute here, though, because you may have more than one `dynamically-generated` element. So using `class="dynamically-generated"` you would write

```
$('.dynamically-generated').hide()
```

Comment: by dynamically generated i mean to say that the id is something like "span01" "span02" "span03".. sorry for the confusion. see my edit

Comment: You can still give all those elements the same class and find them this way! For example `<span id="span01" class="error-message">…</span>` and then `$('.error-message').hide()` will hide *all* of those spans.